# SQL-- what does c.column name AS new columnname mean?

Tags: sql

```
c.[columnname] AS [NEWcolumnname]
```

In SQL, what does c. mean?

Comment: `c` in this case is the name (or alias) of the table in which you can find the `[columnname]` column. In the `FROM` clause you should see something like `FROM c` or `FROM sometable AS c` or `FROM sometable c`

Comment: Thanks, where can i check my table name?

Comment: I just updated my comment suggesting that you go hunt the `FROM` clause. You may see it in `FROM <sometable> AS c` or in a join like `INNER JOIN sometable AS c`

Comment: look in the select query where you got your statement and look where FROM starts the you will find it

Comment: @JNevill Nothing wrong with 1-char aliases, if they work as good mnemonics in the query.

Comment: THOSE ARE FIGHTING WORDS @TheImpaler! (kidding). I've definitely aliased a `customer` table as `c` but I felt dirty.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, c is just an alias that someone assigned..
This c comes from somewhere in your sql query right after a From or a Join or a Column name.
The brackets are mostly optional, you don't absolutely need them in most situations

here's a good example about aliases

```
select m.foodtype as f
from menu as m
left join ingredient as i
on i.type = m.type
```

These aliases are something that you create and assign when you write the sql query.

So for that example it would also be ok if you named it like this:

```
select mymenu.foodtype as RecipeType1
from menu as mymenu
left join ingredient as ingredients
on ingredients.type = mymenu.type
```