# How can I alias this SQL query

Tags: sql

TO practice my SQL skills, I am trying to create a leaderboard by year of stolen bases.

I would like the output to be like this:

```
yearID   playerID_NL  SB  playerID_AL SB
2019     1234         37  5678        32
...
```

To do this, I have a select statement that gets all the leaders, as follows:

```
 select
    yearID, 
    playerID, 
    SB,
    lgID
from
    (select 
        yearID, 
        playerID,
        SB, 
        lgID,
        max(SB) OVER (PARTITION BY yearID, lgID) as max_SB
    from batting) AS max_sb
where 
    SB = max_SB.max_SB;
```

which is works, but there is a row for each league (AL and NL); I want one row per year with the al and nl leader in separate columns;

I would like to alias the above query as `sb_leaders` then join like this to have one row per year:

```
select
    ... -- etc.
from 
    sb_leaders
where
    lgID = 'NL'
outer join
    (
   ... -- same thing as above, except lgID = 'AL'
) al
on 
    sb_leaders.yearID = al.yearID
```

Nevermind if the above `JOIN` is a little off (I can figure out what error that is later.) I can't crate an alias that allows me to select anything from `sb_leader`. It's an error, and typically cryptic like all SQL errors. How can I alias this? Alternatively, if there is a way to avoid deep nested queries besides an alais, that would be great help too.

Comment: I assume this is for SQL Server? Also, can you provide some sample data.

Comment: In addition to the rdbms, how are ties treated? Let's say 2 players tied for the NL. Would you show both for that year as separate rows? And if so, how would the 2nd row appear for the AL columns? Would they be null? This can look odd since you want a wide table output. I personally prefer tall table output and then filter/design downstream in whatever system is pulling the report.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on a path to practice, here's a general and basic idea of how to work with aliases in sql:

[SQL-- what does c.column name AS new columnname mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73025221/sql-what-does-c-column-name-as-new-columnname-mean/73026462#73026462)

You can try using an alias and do a subquery type of structure.

Or you could go try making a temporary table to hold the values in the format that you like, doing this before you run your actual report code. You would use the temporary table name in the From area of your sql statement, and remember to make an alias for it.

I can give you some more hints if you get stuck.